# Close ComboBox DropDown on mouse leave event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, dropdownbox

While developing a simple Windows Form UI applications, I am trying to create an effect to show and close dropdown on mouse events.

Like I can open the dropdown on `MouseMove` event by setting `comboBox.DroppedDown = true;`
However, this same is not working when I set `comboBox.DroppedDown = false;` on `MouseLeave` event to close it.

No idea what exactly is needs to be done here. 
The problem is on `MouseLeave` the dropdown does not lose focus and hence unless you select one item from list, it does not close. It waits for user to select an item from list.
If it can lose focus on `MouseLeave`, would work.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: While the DropDown is Down is has the Mouse __Captured__. Turning that off will make a difference but will not give the desired results. Either a better way of `Releasing` the Capture or some way to follow the mouse events back to the outside controls would be the direction of reaserch..

Comment: You could have some kind of Background worker / Timer working behind on the form, checking if the mouse location (coords) are within the combobox + combobox dropdown menu. If not, you could force a DroppedDown to close. This has an hit on performance, but it should be doable aswell.

Comment: Using Bruno's suggestion in a TimerTick event:`         Point MP =  new Point(Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X,Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y );
        Size DDS = new Size(comboBox1.DropDownWidth, comboBox1.DropDownHeight);
        Rectangle DDR = new Rectangle(new Point(comboBox1.Left, comboBox1.Top + comboBox1.Height) , DDS);
        if (!DDR.Contains(MP) ) {    comboBox1.DroppedDown = false; timer2.Stop(); }`

Answer (score 5):

First of all I must say that I am not an experienced programmer and I just started with WPF.
I know this question is two years old but I had the same issue and I found I can close the drop down list of the ComboBox using the event **IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged**. What was really annoying for me was that I had a ComboBox and a button, and If the drop down menu was opened without making a selection and I wanted to click the button, nothing happens at the first click because at the first click the drop down menu was closing. After this I could click on the button.

For me it's working fine: the drop down list close if I move the mouse in any direction (up, left, down, right) and a message is append to a textbox control. I don't know if this event is something new or it could be used 2 years ago too.

```
private void comPortList_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (comPortList.IsDropDownOpen==true)
        {
            txtMsgBox.AppendText("MouseDirectlyOverChanged\n");
            txtMsgBox.ScrollToEnd();
            comPortList.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }

    }
```

This event triggers when your mouse pointer is over the opened ComboBox. If you don't open the drop down list, it will not trigger.

Another thing that I've seen is that this event triggers when you enter over the opened ComboBox and also when you leave it. If I append the text before checking if the IsDropDownOpen property is true, the text "MouseDirectlyOverChanged" will appear twice in my textbox when I the mouse pointer leaves the oppened ComboBox.

If i comment the line:

```
comPortList.IsDropDownOpen = false;
```

and leave the AppendText and ScrollToEnd before if, the text will append only once.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to be using the MouseEnter event and not MouseMove.  The reason it wouldn't work on MouseLeave is because your mouse is moving, and that will just set it to true again.

Comment: Nope unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I tried just now.